# CSS translate breaks <input> autocomplete list position

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have this weird issue with **Firefox**. Works okay in Chrome.

Basically, a `<input>` inside a div, which has this style:

```
.modal {
    overflow:auto;
    position: fixed;

    top: 50%;
    left:50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

Shows the autocomplete thingy in a totally wrong location, as you can see:

[image]

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MightyPork/T8M7g/31/).

Any solution is welcome. (disabling autocomplete is not really what I want tho).

Comment: It actually has a bug in the BugZilla (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=467442). But I need a *workaround*.

Comment: No, but that has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use translate to position the div, can't you adjust with top and left Unless you are using animation and keyframes translate does not provide that great benefit.

The space on the page that the element occupies remains the same as before transition,so here your autocomplete menu opens at location before the translation.

Comment: It's a modal dialog that must be perfectly centered in the window. And I don't know it's size beforehand, plus I don't like positioning it with JavaScript.

Comment: @MightyPork: Why can't you use something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/T8M7g/30/

Comment: @Misled Obviously, because I don't know how big the dialog will be. It gets bigger based on what the table contains (and there are other dialogs than just the one on the screenshot).

Comment: @MightyPork: So does that mean it's width & height will be `auto` or will they have actual unit values? You can change the dimensions in my demo and it will stay centered.

Comment: @Misled Yeah, auto (if that is default). The fiddle was not perfectly accurate, it's more like: http://jsfiddle.net/MightyPork/T8M7g/31/

Comment: @MightPork: Damn, I guess you're out of luck then.

Answer (score 0):

The autocomplete bug in Firefox seems to get fixed in FF33:

[Comment of Catalin Varga on Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=467442#c40)

Comment: Let's see when firefox 33 is released. I'm at 31 now.